# Notify server about incoming call number with HTTP request

Tags: ios, iphone

I would like to receive a http POST request to my server with phone number of incoming phone call on iPhone.

Is it even possible? I would like to see some ideas how to do this.

Comment: Its not possible. You cannot access call details in your application.

Comment: It is possible to receive call from Mac with Continuity. Probably it is not possible to send notifications from iPhone directly, but maybe from mac? iPhone notifies Mac, Mac notifies server.

Comment: Not possible. None of the framework available to support the functionality that you are expecting.